# com.phone.android keeps crashing immediatelly after factory reset

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, factory-reset, crashes

I am having the very-well known problem where com.android.phone keeps crashing all the time. I have done a factory reset and the problem had immediate effect just after the 1st reboot. So, we can exclude cases like crappy applications.

I know that this is a common problem, but as far as I couldn't find any working solution I decided to ask your help.

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S, Gingerbread, rooted, no custom ROM installed.

Any help appreciated.